# Bind conditional class and var class - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Given the props:

```
someBool = true;
someString = 'set-class'
```

This will add `conditional-class` as a class to the element when `someBool` is true:

```
v-bind:class="{'conditional-class': someBool}"
```

This will add `set-class` to the element as a class:

```
v-bind:class="someString"
```

How do I mix these two syntaxes?

**Tried:**

```
v-bind:class="{'conditional-class': someBool}" v-bind:class="someString"
```

Result: Vue does not support duplicate binds

**Tried:**

```
v-bind:class="[someString, {'conditional-class': someBool}]"
```

Result: only adds 'conditional-class'. Even when the order is reversed.

**Tried:**

```
v-bind:class="{'conditional-class': someBool, someString: true}"
```

Result: treats someString name as a string, class becomes `conditional-class someString`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some ES2015 magic to create a computed property name:

```
:class="{'conditional-class': someBool, [someString]: true}"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Alternatively, one of the things you've already tried should work:

```
:class="[someString, {'conditional-class': someBool}]"
```

This is explicitly documented here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax

I tried older versions of Vue but it seems to have been supported for a long time.

Both techniques are demonstrated here:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      someBool: true,
      someString: 'class2'
    };
  }
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.class1::before {
  content: 'I have class1';
}

.class2 {
  background: #eef;
  margin: 5px;
}

.class2::after {
  content: ' & class2';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div :class="{class1: someBool, [someString]: true}"></div>
  <div :class="[someString, {class1: someBool}]"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Use a computed:

```
v-bind:class="someComputed"

computed:{
    someComputed: function(){
        return (this.someBool ? "conditional-class" + " " : "") 
            + this.someString;
    }
}
```

But that's really the work-around if anyone else comes by scratching their head. OP is looking for a mix inside the binding, or a definitive "not this can't be done" from someone with the ability to be definitive.